# Linux DHCPv6 server for PD on ppp interfaces

Tags: ipv6, dhcp-server, dnsmasq, pppoe, dhcpv6

I need to configure prefix delegation on PPPoE. What is the best DHCPv6 server implementation for this? So far I checked the following:

**isc-dhcp-server** - doesn't work with PPP interfaces

**dibbler** - works, but needs all the interfaces to be present before the server starts so hacks in ipv6-up/down scripts are needed

**dhcp6s (wide)** - works, but delegates prefixes based on DUID only

**dnsmasq** - doesn't do PD

Comment: There's also odhcpd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**dhcpy6d** works, but you need at least **0.7.2.99-5** version (at the moment of writing all the needed features are in beta)

https://dhcpy6d.ifw-dresden.de/download/